# pandas,change particular cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to change particular cell in dataframe?

issue:

```
a new row is adding,instead of modifying the old data
```

when I try to change it like,

```
d1.at[0, 'high'] = 10
```

Comment: what's your `d1`? Looks like it's an integer.

Comment: `d1` needs to be a pandas dataframe. From the error it looks like `d1` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your DataFrame (*d1*) contains something like:

```
   high  low
1     1    2
2     3    4
3     5    6
```

Note that the index does **not** contain *0*.

Then, when you run `d1.at[0, 'high'] = 10`, *Pandas* operates the following way:

- Attempt to find a row with index *0*.
- If the DataFrame in question does not contain such a row then **add**
  a row with such index and all columns set initially to *NaN*.
- In the (just added) row set value in *high* column to *10*.
- Other columns (in this case only *low*) have not been set, so they still
  have *NaN*.
- A side effect is that *both* columns were of *int* type. But even the
  initial, temporary setting of any of their elements to *NaN* coerces these
  columns to *float*.

So after the above instruction *d1* contains:

```
   high  low
1   1.0  2.0
2   3.0  4.0
3   5.0  6.0
0  10.0  NaN
```

**And then let's test another scenario:**

*d1* **does** contain a row with index *0*:

```
   high  low
1     1    2
2     3    4
3     5    6
0     7    8
```

Now if you run `d1.at[0, 'high'] = 10` a "wanted" row has been found
(no insertion took place) and *high* column in this row has been set
to *10* (other columns in these row keep their initial values).

After that *d1* contains:

```
   high  low
1     1    2
2     3    4
3     5    6
0    10    8
```

so:

- *Pandas* **updated** the column in question,
- both columns keep their initial types.